# How can one check an array of errors in chai?

Tags: javascript, typescript, chai

Now I expect something to be thrown from do. But its not a single error, because its an array of errors and each of them not only have a message, but also other properties which have to be checked.

```js
expect(() => do(something)).to.throw()
```

With `.property` I can check for properties, but how do I do it with an array or even just the first element of an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I got something to work. But it doesn't feel really correct.

(using chai-each)

```js
// setup
const f = () => do(something)

// assert the message in each error
expect(f).to.throw().and.to.each.have.property('message').which.eqls('No line breaks are allowed.')

// assert another property in each error
expect(f).to.throw().and.to.each.have.property('character').which.eqls(5)
```

Is there any way to check multiple properties at the same time, or just somehow deep equal with a instance of the same error class? Or maybe even just make this a bit simpler?